# Extend SDWebImage Cache size

Tags: ios, swift, caching, sdwebimage

I've reed that `SDWebImage` is able to cache 1000 of high resolution images only and then the cache will be cleared. i am having the same issue here my app contains lost of images which doesn't reach 500 image but `SDWebImage` cache gets cleared and starts caching from scratch again.

The cache data or age it really doesn't matter for me, i use `SDWebImage` to load images as the following and i just want to cache data without it gets cleared:

```
 let url = NSURL(string: stringurl)
    cell.photos.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil, options:nil, completed: block)
```

Where and how to set the size, please provide clear instructions.

Comment: Are your users going to be ok with that?

Comment: i think so i can handle it , if the device received a memory warning then i can clear the SDWebImage Cache ! @kean

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the cache size. Go to `SDImageCache` and change `static unsigned long long MAX_DISK_USAGE` as per your need.

Comment: There is only the following variable in SDWebimage cache : `static unsigned char kPNGSignatureBytes[8] = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A};` There is no such `static unsigned long long MAX_DISK_USAGE` !!!

Comment: Perhaps changed in the new version. But I still can see /**
 * The maximum number of objects the cache should hold.
 */
 maxMemoryCountLimit;

/**
 * The maximum length of time to keep an image in the cache, in seconds
 */
 maxCacheAge;

/**
 * The maximum size of the cache, in bytes.
 */
 maxCacheSize;

Comment: May you provide where to go and edit, i don't see anything clear lets say i want to make the cache size accept 400 mb or accept 2000 images ? there is no such recourses on the internet to help ! so i may change this : `- (NSUInteger)maxMemoryCountLimit {
    return self.memCache.countLimit;
}` to return 50000 ?